# Spring Data Jpa: Alternating cascade type in @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

There's an entity Box:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name="box")
public class Box {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idbox", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int idbox;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name = "size")
    private BigDecimal size;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Content> content;
}
```

and an entity Content:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name="content")
public class Content {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idcontent", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int idcontent;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Integer amount;

    @Column(name = "shape")
    private String shape;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Box box;
}
```

If I place

> (cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)

In "@ManyToOne" from Box, I delete that Box, keeping children entities (making the box content available to be used for another Box).

Instead, if I use

> (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

the Box is deleted, including children entities (deleting the box and its content).

Let's suppose that in some scenarios, it is needed to delete the Box and its content. Although, in opposite, sometimes I just need to delete the Box but keep its content.

How can I select my desired cascading type based on the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically change the `CascadeType`. You'll need to go with the weakest `CascadeType` and cascade everything above that yourself manually in your application code, i.e. explicitly invoke delete on the children in this case.